# SQL Server 2017 practical experience with adding pre-existing data to temporal tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, temporal-tables

I have done a search in these forums and have come across semi-relevant articles 'Add historic data to system versioned temporal table (SQL Server 2017)' and 'Backfill a temporal table' which cover the technical aspects, i.e. 'how to'. I've got that part covered. What I don't have is practical experience in how an environment that contains say, 700+ system-versioned tables that are being manually populated on an ongoing basis is maintained and any gotchas I am unaware of. If anyone has practical experience and a pragmatic approach in this area and can give me some specific tips about what to look out for that would be greatly appreciated.

We are exploring the possibility of creating temporal tables from data extracted from a source system because we need to carry out point in time reporting.

The data source can be thought of as a CRM solution with hundreds of tables all of different structures some of which have hundreds of columns.

The data source holds information in tables with a structure like this; we have an ETL process that takes these source tables, tacks on start and end dates and produces intermediate tables so we can determine data as at a point in time; example purposes ONLY:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[something]
(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,        <<-- original column from source
    [Name] varchar(200) NULL,            <<-- original column from source
    ...
    [Other columns] varchar(200) NULL,   <<-- original columns from source
    ...
    [ValidFrom] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL, <<-- date/time over which the row is valid; added by ETL
    [ValidTo] [datetime2](7) NULL        <<-- date/time over which the row is valid; added by ETL
)
```

So essentially the intermediate table is in the same structure as a temporal table - except its not a temporal table and I have no control over it!

We need to report out of it and I would prefer that we use temporal queries rather than a lot of additional code.

```
-- We expect to do this:
table1 join table2 on table2.whatever = table1.whatever
       join table3 on table3.whatever = table2.whatever
       join table4 on table4.whatever = table3.whatever

-- But we don't want to have to also do this which we would have to if we were querying the intermediate tables directly:
where @date_as_at between table1.[ValidFrom] and table1.[ValidTo] and
      @date_as_at between table2.[ValidFrom] and table2.[ValidTo] and
      @date_as_at between table3.[ValidFrom] and table3.[ValidTo] and
      @date_as_at between table4.[ValidFrom] and table4.[ValidTo]
```

So looking to take the intermediate tables into a very similar destination structure - except as a temporal table.

Looking for things like:

1. how you authored the automated/templated maintenance of these destination tables (when you followed the steps required to set system versioning on/off and do data insertion what issues, if any, occurred, what did you need to be careful of)
2. how you handled failed loads - for example do you have any tips/code example that allowed you to insert rows in-situ rather than having to run an extract of all data from source
3. any performance problems with data loads - could you do them under a single transaction for example or is this pushing the envelope

Comment: Normally backfilling is a once off operation. You need to be more specific about what you need here

Comment: Altered the original post to show that this would be an ongoing process

Comment: That's not a *system*-versioned table then, so I don't understand why you would set it up as such. Just setup regular history tables, and query and maintain them in the normal fashion

Comment: "700+ system-versioned tables" - uhhhh, why do you have so many tables?

Comment: Added more content/explanation

Comment: In my professional opinion, after having used SQL Server Temporal Tables in a number of projects, they're too fiddly and thwart with cumbersome restrictions to make them worthwhile, and _lots_ of tooling just doesn't work with Temporal Tables. Of particular note is that running an `UPDATE` or `MERGE` query that updates a row _but doesn't actually change anything_ still causes a row-copy into the history table. If you need change-tracking there are likely far better alternatives for your application.

Comment: Its not the change tracking aspect that we are interested in per se as we already have that with our intermediate tables. This is more to do with simplifying usage at the front-end where we are trying to reduce the complexity and surface area of our code base for use in as-at reporting. But I value the points you've made and will take them onboard.